# Trying to get the unique values of subjects in PROC SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

```
Proc SQL NOPRINT;    
        Create Table DSDD as    
        Select DISTINCT (USUBJID),PRIMARY,ARM,ARMN,APTS,DSCOMP_F,APRS,FAS    
            From DERIVED.DSDD    
                Where UPCASE(APTS)="Y";    
Quit
```

I'm wanted the unique values of USUBJID. BUt when I run the above code I get **512** observations. When I the below code I get the count at **490**. I am considering the unique values of USUBJID right? What needs to be done to get the **490** unique observations.

```
Proc SQL NOPRINT;    
        Create Table DSDD as    
        Select COUNT(DISTINCT (USUBJID)) as     COUNT,PRIMARY,ARM,ARMN,APTS,DSCOMP_F,APRS,FAS    
            From DERIVED.DSDD    
                Where UPCASE(APTS)="Y";    
Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` applies for the entire line, not for a single variable.  You can use `group by` to ask it to give you lines grouped by `USUBJID`, but you would need to tell it what to do with the various lines - use things like `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `SUM()` to group those variables; you cannot have any variables not in summary functions that aren't in the group by statement, or you will not get your desired result.